# Using tastypie api from other views

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I am calling tastypie api from normal django views.

```
def test(request):

    view = resolve("/api/v1/albumimage/like/user/%d/" % 2 )

    accept =  request.META.get("HTTP_ACCEPT")
    accept += ",application/json"
    request.META["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = accept   
    res = view.func(request, **view.kwargs)

    return HttpResponse(res._container)
```

[Using tastypie resource in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795463/using-tastypie-resource-in-view)
[Call an API on my server from another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524709/call-an-api-on-my-server-from-another-view)

achieve the same thing but seems harder.

Is my way of calling api acceptable?
Besides, it would be awesome if I could get the result in python dictionary instead of json.
Is it possible?

Comment: No, there is not a proper way to get api response as python dictionary.

Comment: I see `from_json` serializer method, can't it be used somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a dictionary, it means that you must design your application better. Don't do important stuff in your views, nor in the Tastypie methods. Refactor it to have common funcionality.

As a general rule, **views must be small**. No more than 15 lines. That **makes the code readable, reusable and easy to test.**

I'll provide an example to make it clearer, suppose in that Tastypie method you must be creating a Like object, maybe sending a signal:

```
class AlbumImageResource(ModelResource):
    def like_method(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Do some method checking

        Like.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            object=request.data.get("object")
        )
        signals.liked_object(request.user, request.data.get("object"))

        # Something more
```

But, if you need to reuse that behavior in a view, the proper thing would be to factorize that in a different function:

```
# myapp.utils
def like_object(user, object):
    like = Like.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        object=request.data.get("object")
    )
    signals.liked_object(request.user, request.data.get("object"))
    return like
```

Now you can call it from your API method and your view:

```
class AlbumImageResource(ModelResource):
    def like_method(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Do some method checking
        like_object(request.user, request.data.get("object")) # Here!
```

And in your view...

```
# Your view
def test(request, object_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Object, id=object_id)
    like_object(request.user, obj)
    return HttpResponse()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. and this really disappoints me. I originally had `utils` and `view` separated. and I thought tastypie could replace the functionaility of `utils` but I guess not. Why is it called `API framework` then when I apparently need to have now 3 components, `utils`, `view` and the `api`.

Comment: I mean, why then I would use tastypie?  I thought building the core service(utils in your answer) easy&robust is the job of tastypie.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It sucks. Technically, there are some ways to use the API method in your views, but it's not good at all. I think Tastypie was designed with a client in mind. Anyway, if you did separate it before, that's a good thing. Try to do it again, it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for response. When I use tastypie, I have custom filtering(build_filters), data preparation code(dehydrate). I already have those in my `utils`.  So if I need `utils` even when I use tastypie,(resulting in duplicate code), why would I use tastypie?

Comment: Because Tastypie supports all the plumbing to create a REST web service. Maybe you need that. You can easily consume your own web service in your views. Just make an HTTP request, get the response, parse the JSON and you're done. That'd be a different architecture, but that's ok, it's good to have separation of concerns.