# Why isn't tastypie easily usable by other parts of my service? I have duplicate codes in tastypie resource and my core service

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I spent whole week to integrate tastypie into my project and now I can't stop think 'why did I do it'.

I'm using django and tastypie(REST framework) but my question could be applied to other language/frameworks.

My requirements are
1. mobile clients requesting json
2. web clients requesting html and json

So I had

> 1. end_point for json requests(eg, give me images of this user)
> 2. end_point for html requests(give me a user home page with his images and etc)
> 3. core_service(at the bottom) which returns list of images dictionary to #1 and #2

```
def user_image_list_json(request): # 1
   dict = service.user_image_list(request.user_id)
   return serialize_as_json(dict)

def user_home(request): #2
    #build other parts of user home such as `user name`
    dict = service.user_image_list(request.user_id)
    #stuff that dict inside html 
    #build other parts of the page
    return html_response

#3
def image_list_user(user_id, last_image_id,request_comment_count, count):
    if last_image_id is not None:
        last_image_id = int(last_image_id)
        queryset = AlbumImage.objects.select_related().filter(id__lt=last_image_id).filter(album__user_profile__user__id = user_id)
    else:
        queryset = AlbumImage.objects.select_related().filter(album__user_profile__user__id = user_id)

    if count is not None:
        count = min(IMAGE_LIST_COUNT, count)
        queryset = queryset[0:count]
    else:
        count = IMAGE_LIST_COUNT

    album_image_list = list(queryset)

    #dict_list = [album_image.to_dict() for album_image in album_image_list]                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    dict_list = append_comment_list(album_image_list,request_comment_count)
    return dict_list
```

That's how I structured my web service to serve web client and mobile client.
Now I hear REST framework would ease the web development.(This is my first web development)
I adapt tastypie (a django/python REST api framework)

I expected tastypie would replace my code at level #3(the common_service).
But I find it's actually #1/#3 tied together.

If my understanding is correct, I'll end up with

> 1. <s>end_point for json requests(eg, give me images of this user)</s>
> 2. end_point for html requests(give me a user home page with his images)
> 3. core_service(at the bottom) which returns python dictionary to #1 and #2
> 4. tastypie which act as combination of #1/#3

So I still need #3.(the core service) even when I have tastypie.
I find it weird...

[Using tastypie api from other views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647819/using-tastypie-api-from-other-views) is my related question.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of tasty-pie (or any similar framework) stem from designing your code in a RESTful way. In this case, making your models resources.

In the case you've presented, *it's not evident how you've integrated tasty-pie into your project*, which may explain your confusion around the benefits of tasty-pie (or similar frameworks).

`AlbumImage` would be a good candidate for a [resource](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources):

```
class AlbumImageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = AlbumImage.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'album_image'
```

... then, any `AlbumImageResource` could be have a [URI registered](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-resources) ...

```
from myapp.api import AlbumImageResource

album_resource = EntryResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # The normal jazz here...
    (r'^api/', include(album_resource.urls)),
)
```

... and it can be accessed via that URI, in any format:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/album_image/
```

Then, you have a RESTful system that can access content via URIs.

In fact, the documentation [even provides ways to limit access](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#limiting-data-and-access), and [advanced ways to filter and sort data](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html).

Comment: I know tastypie supports auth/filter/sort.. My question is `Why isn't tastypie easily usable by other parts of my service?` Not what it can do.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to change your question from 'Is tastypie worth the trouble' to the question above for clarity?

Comment: You should also take a look at http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views as it is possible (and fairly easy) to invoke the tastypie logic directly without going through the whole hydration/dehydration process.